# Postgres "Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql

I am trying to connect to a test database to run my unit tests on it and for some reason it is failing
but when i connect to my development database everything works just fine

that's my database.ts

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { Pool } from 'pg'

dotenv.config()

const POSTGRES_HOST = process.env.POSTGRES_HOST
const POSTGRES_USER = process.env.POSTGRES_USER
const POSTGRES_PASSWORD: string = process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD!
const POSTGRES_DB = process.env.POSTGRES_DB
const POSTGRES_TEST_DB = process.env.POSTGRES_TEST_DB
const ENV = process.env.ENV

let database

if (ENV === 'dev') {
  database = {
    host: POSTGRES_HOST,
    user: POSTGRES_USER,
    password: POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: POSTGRES_DB
  }
} else if (ENV === 'test') {
  database = {
    host: POSTGRES_HOST,
    database: POSTGRES_TEST_DB,
    user: POSTGRES_USER,
    password: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  }
}

const client = new Pool(database)

export default client
```

and this is my database.json file

```
{
  "dev": {
    "driver": "pg",
    "host": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_HOST" },
    "database": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_DB" },
    "user": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_USER" },
    "password": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD" }
  },
  "test": {
    "driver": "pg",
    "host": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_HOST" },
    "database": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_TEST_DB" },
    "user": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_USER" },
    "password": { "ENV": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD" }
  }
}
```

my .env file

```
PORT=3000
POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
POSTGRES_DB=store
POSTGRES_TEST_DB=test
POSTGRES_TEST_PASSWORD=19992001
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=19992001
SALT_ROUNDS=10
BCRYPT_PASSWORD=123456
TOKEN_SECRET=50
ENV=dev
```

that's my test file

```
import { User, userStore } from '../models/user'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()
const store = new userStore()
const pepper = process.env.BCRYPT_PASSWORD

const user: User = { username: 'test', password: 'test123' }

const pass = bcrypt.hashSync('test_password' + pepper, 10)

describe('User Model', () => {
  it('should have an index method', () => {
    expect(store.index).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('should have a show method', () => {
    expect(store.show).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('should have a create method', () => {
    expect(store.create).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('create method should add a user', async () => {
    const result = await store.create(user)
    if (result) {
      expect(result.username).toBe('test')
    }
  })
})
```

the first 3 tests run just fine but for some reason the last one isn't

and this is the script in package.json that i am using

```
"test": "set ENV=test db-migrate --env test up && jasmine && db-migrate --env test down"
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure it is a string by maybe trying somethings like this

```
    const POSTGRES_PASSWORD = process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD + ""
```

Or in your env type

```
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD="19992001"
```

Comment: no i don't think that is the problem the variable is the same when connecting to the dev db and nothing goes wrong with it nevertheless i tried what you are saying even hard coding the password and it still gives the same error